# invalid XSD with xs:all

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm a beginner with XSD, but this one has me stumped despite intense reading of the specs:

```
<xs:complexType name="iterator">
    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    <xs:all>
        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="element" type="iterator-element" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:all>
</xs:complexType>
```

I'm trying to define something that works like this:

```
<iterator id="123">
   <name>Test</name>
   <element>(data)</element>
   <element>(data)</element>
   <element>(data)</element>
</iterator>
```

In my application, I'll iterate over all those elements.

Is my mistake in syntax or in concept? Should I make name an attribute instead? Should I wrap the elements in something? Why is the XSD parser complaining this:

> s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of 'iterator' is invalid.
>   Element 'all' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

        <xs:element name="iterator" type="iter"/>
        <xs:complexType name="iter">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="element" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

I changed iterator_element because you doesn't explain what is it. Probably complexType ?

On all cases i test on https://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html

This wasn't work because you need declare attributes after the sub elements.

Comment: yes, iterator-element is a complex type I define elsewhere.

Comment: I would prefer if the order of name and element is not important, that's why I use xs:all instead of xs:sequence.

Comment: This is the error if you use xs:all -> ```Cos-all-limited.2: The {max Occurs} Of An Element In An 'all' Model Group Must Be 0 Or 1. The Value 'unbounded' For Element 'element' Is Invalid.``` if my answer help you, close the question giving click to correct answer to my answer, thanks for read.

Comment: doesn't work for me, unfortunately. I might have issues with the nested types.

Comment: Why do not you show us all the code so we can see all the problems?

If you have more problems edit your question please and i will try help.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. I've seen that I have multiple problems in my definitions and refactored them entirely. The new version now works, but it has little to do with the original.